# Rotating mouse following with ease

Tags: jquery

I built a menupage in which I follow the mousemove a way I rotate an image in the middle like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/

```
$(document ).mousemove(function( event ) {

    var mouseX = event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.pageY;
    var offsetX = $(window).width()/2;
    var offsetY = $(window).height()/2;
    var radian = Math.atan2(mouseX - offsetX, mouseY - offsetY);
    var deg = (radian * (180/Math.PI) * -1) + 180;

$('#compassIn').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotateZ(' + deg + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotateZ(' + deg + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotateZ(' + deg + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotateZ(' + deg + 'deg)',
        'transform': 'translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotateZ(' + deg + 'deg)',
    }); 
});
```

The question is how can I add delay and easing to make the rotation smooth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS transition can do miracles here. See the example with:

```
img {transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/622/

```js
var img = $('.image');
if(img.length > 0){
    var offset = img.offset();
    function mouse(evt){
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
```

```css
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:327px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 105px;
    top: 98px;
}
img {transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; width: 50px; height: auto}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="apDiv1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Finger-pointing-icon.png" class="image"/> <br>
    (Not actual picture I'm trying to rotate, but it'll do for now)
</div>
```

Of course, you can tweak the timing, easing, etc. And you should definitely handle the rotation from degree 359 to 0 and vice-versa.

Comment: Without the timing delay the 359 -> 0 works great.  I'm kinda surprised css doesn't do the shortest rotation

Comment: It works great because it happens in an instant. CSS sees it as a scalar animation, so basically it just interpolates numbers from 0 to 359 in the set amount of time. It's actually a pretty common issue in programming - luckily, easy to overcome.